# PYTHON 3x Pyaudio not installing

Tags: python

I have been trying to install pyaudio using cmd on my windows pc which has a python 3x installed. the problem is that i have a microsoft c++ 14.0 installed but its still not installing.Showing error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sg1dypbc\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sg1dypbc\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cu3rluqm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What did you type to install pyaudio?

Comment: install whl file for pyaudio using cmd

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your python version is 3.7, therefore Pyaudio is not gonna install. Try on version 3.6, it should work there.

Answer (score 0):

on your command prompt just simply type
`pip install pipwin`
then enter this
`pipwin install pyaudio`
This works with any python version